# Increasing PHP memory limit (Possible Drupal override?)

Tags: 7

**Problem**

I've recently come across a problem with my dev version of Drupal where I realised the php memory limit isn't high enough.

I've changed the main `php.ini` files but they seem to be ignored and I can only increase the memory limit by putting the following line into `sites/default/settings.php`:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
```

Could there be something Drupal related which is overriding the main settings (that I'm then overriding in `settings.php`) as this is happening in multiple environments?

**Set-Up**

- Windows 7, XAMPP:

Altered php.ini in C:/XAMPP/php/php.ini

```
memory_limit=500M
```

- Ubuntu(10.04), Apache, PHP, MySQL

Altered php.ini in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
memory_limit=500M
```

- Ubuntu(12.04), nginx, PHP-FastCGI, MySQL

Altered php.ini in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
(checked this was correct ini file using `php --ini`)

```
memory_limit=500M
```

I have a php.ini in my drupal root, but it has

```
memory_limit = -1
```

which I'm pretty sure is no limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so a bit of digging and here are the results. The short answer for the first two configs was I couldn't replicate them. Maybe I'd forgotten to restart the server? Not sure.

The two paths I'd listed were the correct paths to change the php memory settings.

However for nginx there is a genuine answer:

1. Although the command `php --ini` says  `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` was loaded the correct file to change is:

`/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

You then have to restart the php process manager not the server because nginx doesn't touch the php.

`sudo service php5-fpm restart`

The reason you have to edit `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file is because `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is the command line php config file and only decides the config for any command line php functions.

Any php functions called by Drupal are processed by FPM and so use the php-fpm config file.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal does not edit any php config settings. The `memory_limit` and what php.ini it is using depends on how your server is setup, there could be something else that is overriding your php.ini you are trying to set. You should use `phpinfo()` to find out what `php.ini` it is using and make sure the last occurrence of memory_limit is set to what ever you want.

Comment: Cheers for the confirmation. I couldn't recreate the first two instances. Not sure what I did wrong, but I did find the explanation for nginx.

Answer (score 2):

Changes to `php.ini` require that the server be restarted. Did you restart Apache after making those changes?

Drupal itself doesn't change memory limits; your use of [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in settings.php is the best way to make the change through PHP execution, but many third-party hosts will not allow that setting to be overridden to overridden.

Finally, I'd recommend setting the memory limit to 512M as that reflects how [semiconductor memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_memory) stores data. There's no real functional advantage of this, though, just OCD :-)

Comment: That's not OCD, just good sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

How to deal with PHP memory not being applied.

1. Check if you're editing the right file by going to Drupal page and you can find the right location of your PHP config file in:

   > Reports -> Status report -> PHP: more information -> Loaded Configuration File: `/etc/.../.../php.ini`
2. Look for `memory_limit` on the same page.
3. Make sure you placed the right value (e.g. `memory_limit = 512M`).
4. Restart your HTTP server, for instance:

   ```
    sudo apache2ctl graceful
   ```

For drush, just run: `drush status` and it would show you the command-line configuration (CLI, which could be different from GUI):

```
$ drush status | grep PHP
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php          
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini 
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
```